# Unable to failback to Primary Service Bus post failover to Secondary?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have an Azure Service Bus in WEST US with Geo-Recovery enabled to sync with EAST US. I could failover to the secondary region EAST US successfully however I could not failback from EAST US to WEST US. I don't have any messages in the WEST US

[image]

however it complains that

> "The Selected namespace is not empty. You must delete all entities
> within the namespace before i tcan be paired"

[image]

Does it mean that I have to completely delete the Service Bus in the WEST US before initiating the Failover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, yes. Once the failover has taken place, the namespace is "burned".

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-geo-dr) is clear about it:

> Only fail forward semantics are supported. In this scenario, you fail over and then re-pair with a new namespace. Failing back is not supported; for example, in a SQL cluster.

Comment: Thank you for your information. Can you please help me with the sample bash script to failover and fail back to the the original service bus? I am not sure how to do this especially cleaning the actual primary service bus.

Comment: I don't work with Bash. There's a sample repo (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-geo-dr#samples) with PowerShell and Python examples you could use to get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a new Service Bus Namespace for performing fail-back from secondary to primary, after primary region recovered. The only thing, you should do to re-use the "old" primary for this purpose, is to delete all topics attached to it.

It's possible to perform this by implementing following algo for fall-back on your side (I did it completely via Azure CLI):

1. Delete topics on the primary
2. Init secondary -> primary pairing
3. Failover secondary -> primary
4. Delete topics on the secondary
5. Init primary -> secondary pairing

This will allow you to do zero-downtime fail-forward and fail-back, because all time the same alias URL will be used.

You could do this even if you setup Iac (f.E. per Terraform). After fail-back you will have the same Terraform state, as you had before failover / fail-forward.

Note: after fail-forward not the full cloud state will be mirrored in the Terraform (Terraform has no idea about your failover). To prevent problems, it's good idea freeze Terraform deployment, until the primary region is back / you have performed fail-back.